# Impulse Response of LTI Systems to Dirac Delta

Tags: math, lti-system

I am reading a book on Linear Time-Invariant systems and came across the following:

$$y(t) = T\{x(t)\}$$

where input $$x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\text{d}\tau$$

\$\delta\$ is the Dirac delta function, and the LTI system is represented by \$T\$.

The book concluded that:

$$y(t)=T\Big\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\text{d}\tau\Big\} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)T\{\delta(t-\tau)\}\text{d}\tau = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x(\tau)h(t-\tau)\text{d}\tau$$

where \$h(t)\$ is the impulse response of the LTI system to \$\delta(t)\$.

My question is why \$T\$ is not applied to \$x\$ as in the following:

$$y(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty T\{x(\tau)\}T\{\delta(t-\tau)\}\text{d}\tau$$

**Update**

I think \$T\$ is applied to the integrand, both \$x(\tau)\$ and \$\delta(t-\tau)\$ but since \$x\$ at a specific \$\tau\$ is a single value not a function and therefore:

$$T\big\{x(\tau)\delta(t-\tau)\big\} = x(\tau)T\{\delta(t-\tau)\}$$

Is this a correct explanation?

Comment: simply because it isn't. \$T\{\}\$ is already a convolution. There's not much to talk about here - it's simply not how we defined our terminology.

Comment: Which book? Can you please give the reference?

Comment: @MarcusMüller please see my updated post. Thank you.

Comment: What does T represent?

Comment: @Chu according to the definition, \$T\$ represents the LTI system, so \$T\{x\}\$ would mean you appy \$T\$ to the signal \$x\$.

Comment: @user578 no, that is not a correct explanation. you cannot just pull $x(\tau)$ out of your LTI system! That makes no sense - neither mathematically, nor physically.

Comment: @PeterK. The book is Schaum's Outline of Signals and Systems, 3rd Edition (Schaum's Outlines) 3rd Edition by Hwei Hsu.

Comment: @Chu \$T\$ is the transfer function that gets the input \$x\$ and outputs \$y\$.